# Google Photos REST API with Angular/Java/dotNet

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-api-java-client, google-photos-api

I am trying to connect to google photo in angular and been searching since last two days about google photos REST api but couldn't find any useful example.

Could somebody help me with this on how to use google photos api in angular. an example would be great if I get it working I will creating sample and put it on github or others to look at.

Another thing I am trying is to connect api without any user interaction. I have tried playgrounds but its prompting to authorize access as well. Idea is to build ionic app that can connect to my google photos without needing me to authenticate access to it with my id and secret.

my app would be in angular(ionic) or java(android) so would prefer example (if any) in those platform but ok with dotnet or php as well. Won't be able to use library in dotnet or php.

Thanks
Bhavesh

Comment: After some googleing in google docs, there is a library for google photos api which you should enable for your google account, and then you need to implement it for devices you want to use (android and ios) and for each device or platform you choose you should put package name and some details about your app or web , then there you will be asked to set if data you need to show belongs to you or belongs to google users, and as i saw (fast look) in setting for android they asked for show to google users and not for your data cause of security reasons for android but in this way you can start.

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, I have enabled api for web application and others and have got cilentId and secret and have tried that in android app with java library available but it asks for authentication on first connect and after that it throwing  " Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt"